# Running the WSO2 Application Manager docker image with custom configuration

Tags: css, shell, docker, wso2, wso2-appm

Still new to Docker. I have created a WSO2 docker image successfully using instructions available [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DF120/Building+Docker+Images).

I would like to run it (`wso2am:2.0.0`) with a custom CSS file. I am doing some reading, but I am facing issues.

- The Docker image runs fine when I perform `docker run wso2am:2.0.0`.
- I have replicated the directory structure of `wso2am` at `/home/me/Desktop/some-path` and put my css file in the proper directory. I am under Ubuntu 14.

I am facing two issues:

1. I would like to run my `wso2am` image with my directory structure on top of it, but without making a permanent change to my `wso2am` image files. That is, if I stop the container/image, it does not matter if the copied files from my directory structure are not persisted. What is the exact command to perform?
2. The Docker documentation often mentions `-t -i` as options to access the container. However, when I launch `docker run -it wso2am:2.0.0 bash`, I don't get a shell access to explore the directory structure of my container. It just dumps all debug statements (the log). Why?

**Remark**
Regarding 1., it does not seem like the right to proceed. I should make a copy of my `Dockerfile` and add instructions to copy my extra files, then build an image.

Comment: Can you please share the docker file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below command. This will give you shell access to a running container.

```
docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> /bin/bash
```

To get the CONTAINER_ID issue `docker ps` command first which will list down all running containers with their CONTAINER_IDs.

The reason it dumps logs when you execute with `-i -t` is that it starts the carbon server during the `docker run` in foreground. Therefore, you cannot execute any other shell commands in this mode. I am assuming that you might have configured this way in your docker file. Share your dockerfile if this doesn't answer the question.

Are you using dockerfiles from WSO2 docker repository?

Comment: Yes, I am using dockerfiles from WSO2 repository. I'll try what you suggest when I am back to work this week. Thanks.

Comment: A comment on above 1, what you can do is not to copy the docker file, but to write your own docker file with wso2am:2.0.0 as base image. "FROM wso2/wso2am:2.0.0"